# Post-Transformer RMS Voltage for This Circuit?

Tags: design, transformer, circuit-analysis

I am confused here. For the below circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIZEvX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Ripple voltage is given as 1V peak to peak, Vo = 15V DC. I have assumed a 0.7V drop across any given diode. *Please note that I was a little hasty in my construction. I do not know the values of the capacitors or resistors yet.* The transformer line has 60 Hz frequency.

I'm trying to find the transformer rms voltage to the circuit where the turns of the transformer are not known.

I calculated: 2*16V + 1.4V, since there are two diode drops, the center tap configuration giving two instances of the maximum load voltage, which is 15V + 1V ripple. This gives 33.4V, which, dividing by sqrt(2) for rms gives about 23.6V (rms). However, the given answer is 22.9V (rms)

What am I missing in my calculation? Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try 2*15.5+1.4. Ripple goes up and down.

Comment: Ahh my God! Of course! A peak to peak ripple of 1V is +/- 0.5V. Thanks, I feel stupid for having missed it, but I really appreciate you pointing it out!

Comment: I Think you're missing a ground at the midpoint of the two capacitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want 30Vdc, the peak AC voltage has to be 30V + 2 diodes = 31.4Vpk. The RMS is this divided by sqrt(2) = 22.2V RMS. This takes no account of ripple. If you factor ripple into the equation then you can assume the 30V is in fact 30V +/-1V. This equates to half the supply being 15V +/-0.5V i.e. 1Vp-p ripple.

So now the peak AC voltage is 31V + 2 diodes = 32.4Vpk. The RMS is then 22.9V.

As this appears to be the "correct" answer I can see that when you added onto the 30V the peak ripple you used twice as much - remember the ripple is peak-to-peak and only half of that counts towards pushing up the peak AC voltage.